was gitpod able to show code being updated live if another person has access to your project?
I recently wanted to start doing a fun little project with a friend using Gitpod. we wanted to use a text editor that allowed you to write code on one end and have it updated live on the other end (like how a Google Docs works) without having to commit or push or anything of that. I could've swore Gitpod was like this in the past but now it doesn't seem to have this feature. Am I right? or is there something we need to switch in the settings to allow this functionally?
We tried to see how the commit works but it just wasn't like how I remembered.
